# If I use routeTemplate "api/{controller}" and don't specify routeParameter in Routes how do I call specific method from value controller?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

My routes config look like this

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ActiontApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}"

        );
```

How can I call method with parameter in my values controller?

```
  public string Get()
    {
    ....
    }

    public string GetByName(string name)
{
......
}
```

How can I call GetByName method using http.get in angular controller?

Comment: what is the desired url you want to call?

Answer (score 0):

Your Route Code should look like

```
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{Name}",
        defaults: new { Name = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

and Action Code look like this

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/GetByName/{name}")]
    public string GetByName(string name)
```

and call this action from angularjs like

```
var result = $http({
              method: "GET",
              url: "api/{CONTROLLER NAME}/GetByName",
              data: JSON.stringify({ Name: "Raju" })
          });
          result.then(function (pl) {
           //Success code
          },
          function (errorPl) {
          //Error Code
           });
```

Comment: I did that before I thought - if someone will pass data that will crash the server. How can I prevent this without exposing queries on the client side?

Comment: can you send sample of code, please send me code zip file(upload on google drive and send me link), i will check on my end.

Comment: @RajuDetroja you are using Attribute routing on action but have not enabled attribute routing on config. `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();`. The route template in route attribute is also wrong compared to what you have in the script

Comment: for this find code look like -    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();, code updated , thank you for suggest